# In Column Highcharts, Custom Add text with specific offset

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I want to add text to a specific offset in hightcharts.

Answer (score 0):

Custom text can be added using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`. Check code and demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
  chart.renderer
    .text('text', 150, 80)
    .css({
      color: '#4572A7',
      fontSize: '16px'
    })
    .add();
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kejpsvth/

**API:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text